# Where is clipboard data stored?

Tags: macos

Is there an actual file where the data is stored while I have something in my clipboard?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pasteboard is handled by `pbs` process on OS X. Things which are copied are stored inside `pbs` address space. More about that is on Apple [Pasteboard Server](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PasteboardGuide106/Articles/pbConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008101-SW8) article.

> Whether the data is transferred between objects in the same application or two different applications, in a Cocoa application the interface is the same—an NSPasteboard object accesses a shared repository where writers and readers meet to exchange data. The writer, referred to as the pasteboard owner, deposits data on a pasteboard instance and moves on. The reader then accesses the pasteboard asynchronously, at some unspecified point in the future. By that time, the writer object may not even exist anymore. For example, a user may have closed the source document or quit the application.
>
> Consequently, when moving data between two different applications, and therefore two different address spaces, a third memory space gets involved so the data persists even in the absence of the source. NSPasteboard provides access to a third address space—a pasteboard server process (pbs)—that is always running in the background. The pasteboard server maintains an arbitrary number of individual pasteboards to distinguish among several concurrent data transfers.

Answer (score 6):

As Mateusz pointed out, there's no file with this information. However, you can use `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` to manipulate the pasteboard.

For example, `ls | pbcopy` will copy the output (stdout) of `ls` to the pasteboard.

[Man page for pbcopy.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbcopy.1.html)

Answer (score 4):

The pasteboard server process is `pboard` *not* `pbs`, and you can verify that by checking the man pages for both.

Now that we know the correct process we can:

1. load up *Activity Monitor*
2. search for the `pboard` process
3. get info using <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>
4. view *Open Files and Ports*

We can see that the only files it has open are itself, dyld and the dyld cache.

[image]

Comment: It seems you are correct. I've opened the Console.app and after copying something I get logs from the `pboard` process. Strange that the info on Appe site is wrong. +1

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek yes it is strange. I've reported it but it's not been changed so far.